# Sapi PHP теория основы

Tags: php, php-fpm, cgi, теория

Всем привет! Изучая Nginx дошел до того, что есть SAPI, и что их несколько видов и бла,бла,бла. Вопрос: у нас есть сервер(демон, который ждёт, когда же к нему придет запрос) и есть механизм обработки (запрос/сервер -> пхп интерпретатор -> ответ/сервер)

Вопрос возник в том свете, что Апач в моих глазаг, это:

1. Пришел запрос на 80й порт, его смотрит Апач.
2. Увидев, что есть запрос, демон принимает его в работу, и тут же, использует свой модуль для обработки

Тогда как CGI/FastCGI/FPM ==> то же самое, только программа, которая на 80 порту другая, и php интерпретатор установлен как самостоятельное приложение, а не подпрограмма

Правильно ли, что SAPI, - это механизм, который определяет, как и куда сервер будет стучатся для обработки запроса, а так же куда и как вернуть эти данные обратно ?

Вопрос 2: как система понимает, что я запрос пришел через cli или mod_apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Правильно ли, что SAPI, - это механизм, который определяет, как и куда
>   сервер будет стучатся для обработки запроса, а так же куда и как
>   вернуть эти данные обратно ?

Частично, если на пальцах то так:

`[Клиент] <---> [WEB-Server] <----- SAPI ------> ([ZEND] <---> [PHP])`

Тогда как ваши `CGI/FastCGI/FPM` как раз и являются `SAPI`.

Наглядно можно так:

`[Apache] <----- CGI------> [PHP]`

> Вопрос 2: как система понимает, что я запрос пришел через cli или
>   mod_apache

Обычно вы работаете только с одним `SAPI`.

Вы немного запутались. Что значит **система**? Нет никакой **системы**.

В общем плане: апачу надо обработать запрос, у него есть набор инструментов (`SAPI`), которыми он этот запрос может выполнить. Обычно вы берете один инструмент, который выгоден для вашей задачи, и всегда с ним работаете. Вы берете к примеру `CGI`, и говорите `ZEND`-y, вот мне нужен результат работы конкретного скрипта (апач уже знает какой нужен), верни мне результат, по стандарту `CGI`. Тогда `ZEND` говорит, а есть ли у меня информация, что такое стандарт `CGI`, смотрит в свой кармашек и видит, что есть (ибо все что вы назвали поддерживается в php из коробки и даже больше). Раз есть, то отправляем на работу интерпретатору php, он дает результат и `zend` по стандарту отправляет обратно.

---

В `PHP` проверить `SAPI` можно так: `php_sapi_name()`.

Comment: @AlexKhonko Что?

Comment: Простите, не заметил, что часть вопроса только записалась. Получается, что SAPI - всего лишь набор инструкций, по котором сервер знает как именно нужно передать данные на исполнение интерпретатору